# How to build a download counter in django

Tags: django, download, counter

I am building a freebie website where I allow users to download my source files when they click on the download button. I would like to get the total downloads for each item. Since I am still learning. I need to know what approach I should take to build this. Appreciated it in advance as I have learned soo much from this community. So to summarize I need to have a download counter on each item in admin to know how many times this item has been downloaded.

Comment: An easy way can be to have an attribute in your model, something like counter. Whenever API hits, in the views you can increment the attribute of the model.

Comment: thanks a lot, i will try that